# JSONB array elements index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

We have tables in Postgres 11:

```
_order
-----------
id

items: jsonb: [{'id': 1},{'id': 5}...]

property
-----------
item_id

value
```

We need to get list of orders with array of items for each order, where `property.value` is set.

I use such query:

```sql
select
     _order.*,
     jsonb_agg(distinct property.value) filter (where property.value is not null) as listed_items
from _order
left join jsonb_array_elements(items) jae on true
left join property on ((jae->'id')::int = property.id)
group by _order.id

_order.id, property.item_id - primary keys
```

With real data (8k order with 500 items each, total is about ~4mil rows) query works too slow - about 25 seconds.

After adding GIN index on `_order.items`, query began to work for 15 second, but it is slow the same.

The question: how can i build index for array `id` from jsonb? I found how can I do this this simple key values, but not for array.

Maybe you have any ideas how to optimize query for currency database schema?

Comment: There is no index that could support `jsonb_array_elements()`. The model is poorly designed. You need to normalize it by creating a new table that contains the array elements as rows.

Comment: I agree with klin: that's the price you pay for de-normalizing

Comment: If you can't normalize your data, can you then remove the redundant id from the array and just store a plain list? So `[1,5]` instead of `[{'id': 1},{'id': 5}]` that would allow a simpler join that does not require the unnesting

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
I cannot use array like [1,5], because i store in json some field for items, like a 'price'.

Comment: What good could the index be?  Your "LEFT JOIN"s mean you are returning the entire table anyway.